# animate image with opicity in javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript

This code is suppose to hide image and then show image in slow manner but it is directly show no image and full image

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=1.0;
function trans()
{
document.getElementById("img1").style.opacity=a;
if(a>0)
a=a-0.1;
else
a=1.0;
Window.setTimeout(trans(),1000);
 }

</script>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body onload="trans();">
<img id="img1" src="img/image1.jpg" width="225" height="225"  />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

- Use `window.setTimeout` not `Window` ... notice the casing
- Instead of invoking `trans()` in your setTimeout, you should pass only the function name `trans`.

`window.setTimeout(trans,1000);`

OR if you insist on invoking then wrap it with an anonymouns function.

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    trans();
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, "trans()" instead of trans(), the latter is a call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=1.0;
function trans()
{
  document.getElementById("img1").style.opacity=a;
  if(a>0)
    a=a-0.1;
  else
    a=1.0;
  window.setTimeout("trans()",1000);
}

</script>
<style>

</style>
</head>

<body onload="trans();">
<img id="img1" src="img/image1.jpg" width="225" height="225"  />
</body>
</html>
```